# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication

Error i got is

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  C:\Users\Jangid\Downloads\TestWebSite1\TestWebSite1\Backup\TestWebSite1\Web.config  26
```

I have hosted a website in a server using ASP.Net 2.0, i have a web.config in the root folder and also one in the Admin folder, but the admin folder is not a virtual directory and i dont want to create.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Admin/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Admins"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

But for authentication and login work for Admin folder, i have used ASP.Net Login Control, but this error preventing me to move formward.

And also please can any one give me a link for learning ASP.Net Login Control, Like user who visit Admin folder should be authenticated with a Role as admin,
How can i create a Role and assign to user on a server

Comment: this link explains the error message and why it occurs. http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/02/17/163375.aspx. As Koneru said certain config elements should be kept in the global web.config i.e at the root level and authentication is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<system.web>       
    <authentication mode="Forms"> 
        <forms name="cokiename" 
            loginUrl="./protectedFolder/login.aspx" 
            protection="All" 
        timeout="60" 
        defaultUrl="./protectedFolder/protectedPafe.aspx"/> 
  </authentication> 
</system.web>
```

This should be in your main web.config file

Following goes into your sub directory config

```
<configuration> 
<system.web> 

  <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
    <authorization> 
      <deny users="?" /> 
    </authorization> 

</system.web> 
</configuration>
```

protected folder contains the login page, protected pages and the web.config

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the authentication tag in your main web.config.
Separate Login page for admins is not required.
You need to create admin role in your membership database.(can do using asp.net website administrator)
This is how you work with membership database 
http://revenmerchantservices.com/page/ASpnet-20-step-by-step-Membership-Provider-.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx

This is for role based security using which you can secure your directories(virtual)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/formsroleauth.aspx

Comment: But i want to have login access only for the admin folder, because when a comman user visits a website, he should not be directed to login page, if i give the path as http://www.dignaj.com/ Admin then only the user is required for login