# Is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net

When i m trying to run my asp site it comes this error:

Configuration Error Description: 
An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

How can i fix this error?

Comment: visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468967/machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level-what-does-this-error-means/10469022#10469022

Comment: Maybe you can check this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500147/it-is-an-error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplicat

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a virtual directory in VS. Right-click on project node in Solution Explorer, select Properties. Click on Web tab and choose "Create Virtual Directory".